# Excel distinct count in Pivot Table by all period segmented by month

Tags: excel, pivot

Okay, as I see it now this isn't the real problem.

I need to get distinct count of customers by month, taking into account all 
previous months. What I get by distinct count now is the unique count for a single month, but not taking into account the whole period. That is done by grand total but i need it segmented by month. Is there any way to fix this?

What I have now:

-2016.04 Subtotal 3
        A 1
        B 1
        C 1
-2016.05 Subtotal 3
       A 1
       B 1
       G 1
-Grand Total 4

What I need:

-2016.04 Subtotal 3
        A 1
        B 1
        C 1
-2016.05 Subtotal 1
       A 1
       B 1
       G 1
-Grand Total 4

Comment: You cannot delete data using a Pivot Table. Do you want to delete the non-first occurrences within your data? If yes, you may use **Data** / **Remove Duplicates** feature?

Comment: I wasn't clear enough. If you use distinct count in pivot table it basically hides, i.e. "deletes", duplicate values. I don't need them deleted from the main table that I pivoted.The question concerns only data in the pivot table and the mentioned columns are in the pivot table.

Comment: Hard to express the problem this way. We may understand better if you may provide some sample data and the desired output as a screenshot etc.

Comment: Okay, as I see it now this isn't the real problem.

I need to get distinct count of customers by month, taking into account all previous months. What I get by distinct count now is the unique count for a single month, but not taking into account the whole period. Is there any way to fix this?